# Disable decoration for pgfplot nested in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, decorations

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw node[draw, decorate, decoration={random steps}] (box) at (0,0) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{decorate=false} % does not affect axes
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[] table[row sep=crcr] {
                30 4\\
                42 4\\
                42 3.5\\
                50 3.5\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`\tikzset{decorate=false}` works to disable decoration on the graph itself, but not on its axes:

[image]

How to disable decoration for the whole plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you need to set `decoration={name=none}` to disable the decoration in this context:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw node[draw, decorate, decoration={random steps}] (box) at (0,0) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{decoration={name=none}}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[] table[row sep=crcr] {
                30 4\\
                42 4\\
                42 3.5\\
                50 3.5\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```